# SSIS AND XLSM load time issue Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am having the following issue of SSIS AND XLSM load time issue Visual Studio 2010

I want to speed this up

I am reading a .xlsm as my excel source

I have noticed its loading / reading every row of the excel...even though they are blank

e.g I only have 300 + rows of data at the moment, but it loading every row even though they are blank e.g going pass the 400 row where there is no data yet

I don't want it reading 200,000+ rows before it actually loads the 300

how do I stop this please team

Comment: Is this a situation where you originally had 200k rows in the file, and deleted all but 300?

Comment: no, ive only been adding the rows over the last few months , only now at the 300 row mark. please help

Comment: if it cant be stopped, is there a way of saying stop on row 1000 just to speed up package please?

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the 300 lines into a new Excel file?

Comment: there are a lot of macros set up, unfortunately its not the case of copying and pasting the row :+( please help

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using an sql command in the excel properties, and only import where ID IS NOT NULL x

thank team for ideas x